# How to set icon on wxFrame?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

How can I add an icon (.ico file) to a wxFrame?

I was looking in the [docs](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Frame-class.html) but can't find any mention of `icon`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried this setting in py2exe setup file, but it didn't do anything:

```
windows = [
        {
            "script": "myscript.py",
            "icon_resources": [(1, "icon.ico")]
        }
    ],
```

But this ended up working. Self is wx.Frame instance:

```
icon = wx.EmptyIcon()
icon.CopyFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap("icon.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))
self.SetIcon(icon)
```

Hope this helps some others.

Comment: I do both for my app. For py2exe packaged app to show an icon on windows task bar, it's good idea to set an icon file with multiple sizes embedded. But, wx.Frame will need wx.Bitmap stuff.

Comment: `wx.IconFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap("icon.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))` is a shortcut for that.

Answer (score 12):

Phoenix wxpython:

```
frame.SetIcon(wx.Icon("path/to/app.ico"))
```

Classic wxpython:

```
frame.SetIcon(wx.IconFromLocation("path/to/app.ico"))
```

Answer (score 1):

**wxWidgets** support the *platform independent* XPM format, which is technically a header file with extension **.xpm**, containing an array of string constants, e.g.

```
/* XPM */
static const char *icon_xnp1[] = {
/* columns rows colors chars-per-pixel */
"32 32 182 2 ",
"   c black",
".  c #0D0F13",
... };
```

There are online tools to create this format, e.g.
https://de.onlineconvert.com/icon-to-xpm .

The icon is set by

```
wxFrame frame;
...
frame.SetIcon(icon_xnp1))
```

which deploys an implicit wxIcon constructor

```
frame.SetIcon(wxIcon(icon_xnp1))) .
```

Comment: @admin saw this is python domain, can be removed

Answer (score 0):

`self.SetIcon("app.ico")` or `frame.SetIcon(wx.Icon("app.ico"))` certainly works when run code, but it won't work after packaged by pyinstaller.

The way it handles in [this video](https://youtu.be/077hU10WuK0?si=VpXObRM-tTkQHXsw) works in executable. You'll need to package it like this: `pyinstaller --icon=name.png --onefile --noconsole app.py`

Here is the code from Youtube:

```
icon = wx.IconLocation(sys.executable, 0)
self.SetIcon(wx.Icon(icon))
```