# How do I add an icon to my app in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm messing around with wxpython and I want to make a good app, and I want an icon for my app. (I mean on the actual window not the taskbar.)

I've already read [How to set icon on wxFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002573/how-to-set-icon-on-wxframe#25002882). But where do I put the path to my icon in the wx.EmptyIcon()?
I really don't understand how to do this. Any help?

Sorry for the bad english!

Comment: link shows you have to put path in `icon.CopyFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap(PATH))`, not directly in `wx.EmptyIcon()`

Comment: I'm so stupid. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, for anyone who wants to know, I figured it out. You need to use this code:

```
frame.SetIcon(wx.Icon("C:\\Users\\JScripter98\\Downloads\\scissors.png"))
```

(the path can be anything you want)

This sets the icon to your main frame. The path should have two \'s in it so python knows it's a file path.